# How to change articles/view/slug to articles/slug in CakePHP with Routing

Tags: cakephp, routes

I would like to have a route setup on my CakePHP app that will accomplish the following:

- I have my app setup to use Slugs that usually generate addresses as

`http://www.domain.com/articles/view/my-favorite-cakephp-application`

- However, I would like the address to display as

`http://www.domain.com/articles/my-favorite-cakephp-application`

How can I accomplish that using routes.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in routes.php

> Router::connect(
>       '/articles/*',
>       array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view')
>   );

Comment: That does not work since it will try to route anything that is there. For example if I have http://www.mydomain.com/articles/index, it will send it to http://www.mydomain.com/articles/view and send it again to http://www.mydomain.com/articles/view causing an infinite loop.

Comment: if you have other methods (index, add, etc.) just add the routes for them before that. So for examples: Router::connect( '/articles/', array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'index') );Router::connect( '/articles/add/*', array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'add') );Router::connect( '/articles/*', array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view') ); If you use prefix, you also need to add rules for them too.

Comment: Yeah that would be too complicated. However, I got to say you were very close. I was able to fix this based on the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109461/cakephp-how-to-do-reverse-routing-with-slug . Per this guy's suggestion, I changed my route to `Router::connect('/article/*',array('controller' => 'articles', 'action' => 'view'));`. The only thing you missed is that in the link the controller needs to be singular (`article` instead of `articles`). Excellent though....